# Traffic from OpenVPN client to 'self' rejected by UFW

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn, ufw

I currently have a single VPS set up with OpenVPN server. My idea behind this setup is that, while developing, I would be connected to server over VPN, which would allow me to access ports on the server that are blocked by iptables/ufw for the outside world.

OpenVPN has been set up such that is masqueraded and forwards all traffic. This works pretty well for any external website. However when I attempt to access some service/port running on the server itself, the request does not seem to be masquaraded nor does the server view it as request made from a client of the tun0 interface and therefore based on the UFW rules set the request is blocked.

I do not have alot of experience with setting up a vpn or custom routing, so my question is: what configuration am I missing such that requests made from a OpenVPN client are allowed?

In my `before.rules`:

```
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0] 
# Allow traffic from OpenVPN client to eth0
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/8 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
```

Error when accessing a service on the server itself (from a connected client):

```
[UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=[...] SRC=[MY-ACTUAL-CLIENT-IP] DST=[SERVER-IP] LEN=60 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x00 TTL=55 ID=46182 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=47449 DPT=9332 WINDOW=14600 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are blocking the incoming VPN connection.  All client VPN traffic should be tunneled over the VPN connection

Masquerading should already be caught by an existing rule for all outgoing connections on eth0.  You shouldn't need to add this rule.

VPN connections will have a different device.  You may need to add accept rules for that device.  The naming of the device depends on the firewall and how they are creating the virtual interface they use.